# Change Image to gif on scroll with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to change a couple of images to gifs as you scroll down the page. Currently I have the images changing to gifs on scroll, but the gif resets as soon as you scroll again. I would like the gif to continue to play even if you are scrolling.

Here is my jquery:

```
  $(window).scroll(function(){
  var top = $(window).scrollTop();

  var img1Top = $('.wrap').offset().top;
  if(img1Top){
    $('.wrap').attr('src','../wrap.gif');
  };


  var img2Top = $('.vest').offset().top;
  if(top=(img2Top)){
    $('.vest').attr('src','../vest.gif');
  };

  var img3Top = $('.loop').offset().top;
  if(top=(img3Top)){
    $('.loop').attr('src','../loop.gif');
  };

});
```

Comment: You want the images should be replaced only once? When user scroll first time from top to bottom?

Comment: I will have 3 separate images, and as you scroll each one should change ti a gif as you scroll that the div that its in

Comment: Yes I got that point. But when you scroll again the GIF loads again and that is what you dont want. RIght?

Comment: Correct. Once the gif starts I would like it to continue playing even if you scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Your code is currently resetting the `src` every time the page scrolls, and although the path may not be changing, it will cause the image to refresh.

You need to wrap each `src` change in a conditional that only updates the image if it *hasn't already been updated*.

**2.** Your `if` statements are using `=` instead of `==`, which won't work.

**3.** Doing `==` to compare the top of the window to the top of the elements is not the best way to do this, only because if you scroll fast enough, the chances of this event being called when the two values are identical are *very* slim. You should use `>=` instead.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var top = $(window).scrollTop();

  var img1Top = $('.wrap').offset().top;
  if(img1Top && $('.wrap').attr('src') != '../wrap.gif'){
    $('.wrap').attr('src','../wrap.gif');
  };


  var img2Top = $('.vest').offset().top;
  if(top >= img2Top && $('.vest').attr('src') != '../vest.gif'){
    $('.vest').attr('src','../vest.gif');
  };

  var img3Top = $('.loop').offset().top;
  if(top >= img3Top && $('.loop').attr('src') != '../loop.gif'){
    $('.loop').attr('src','../loop.gif');
  };

});
```

Comment: Thank for this! I tried this , but now its playing all the gifs at beginning and not when you scroll to the specific div class

Comment: @AndrewC This is a syntax issue with your original code that I hadn't previously noticed. You have `top=(img2Top)` in your code, but you need this  to be `==` instead of just `=`. I have fixed my post to reflect this.

Comment: good catch! I tried the update and the first image works, but the others do not.

Comment: @AndrewC Was the code in your original post working beforehand? I was under the impression that it was already preforming as intended, and so I made no attempts to debug your code. That being said, you'd probably need to sort out your `==` simply because when you scroll, the odds of you hitting that exact pixel amount to trigger the `==` are slim.

Comment: yes it was working before. The only issue I was having is the gif kept restarting as you would scroll

Comment: Did you copy+paste your working code or did you attempt to simplify it for this post? I find it hard to believe your code was working when you were using `=` instead of `==`. That being said, check my edited answer.

Comment: Yeah, I copied exactly what I was using. Your solution is a bit off but I can change that. Thanks for the help! Side question, the gif plays once, but what if I wanted the gif to restart if you were to scroll back up to that certain point again?

Comment: You would specify an `else if` or an `or` conditional to say "if the `src` has already changed and the scrollTop is *less* than the top of the element, reset the `src`."

Comment: Thank you for the help @Santi

Answer (score 1):

Try with this.
I have initialized a variable `changed` and on load of each gif incremented it and check changed variable in each condition like below. So each gif will be loaded only once not repeatedly.

```
var changed = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var top = $(window).scrollTop();

    var img1Top = $('.wrap').offset().top;
    if(img1Top && changed != 1){
        $('.wrap').attr('src','../wrap.gif');
        changed++;
    };


    var img2Top = $('.vest').offset().top;
    if(top==(img2Top) && changed != 2){
        $('.vest').attr('src','../vest.gif');
        changed++;
    };

    var img3Top = $('.loop').offset().top;
    if(top==(img3Top) && changed != 3){
        $('.loop').attr('src','../loop.gif');
        changed++;
    };

});
```

Comment: Thank for this! I tried this , but now its playing all the gifs at beginning and not when you scroll to the specific div class

Comment: Check updated answer... Error was in if conditions.. it should be double equal to instead of one..

Answer (score 0):

**I would try solving this using attributes in Jquery and a div in HTML as a trigger to change the image source as the user scrolls down the page.**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="trigger"></div><img src="JPG_URL_HERE" />
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(function() {
  var $window = $(window);
  var endpoint = $("#trigger").offset().top - $window.height();
  $window.on('scroll', function() {
    if ((endpoint) < $window.scrollTop()) {
      $("img[src='JPG_URL_HERE']").attr("src", "GIF_URL_HERE");
    }
  });
});
```

**I created an example for you** [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/JonnyEcho/y24wrfmy/)